# AngularJS & Protractor - How to check if elemenent was displayed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I want to test if my AngularJS app is displaying a loading circle while the app is waiting for a response from a async call.

How can I check is the loading circle is displayed, because `expect()` seems to be fired when the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1):

This is the default `protractor`'s behavior. In order to change it, temporarily change `browser.ignoreSynchronization` to `true` before making an action triggering the loading circle to appear and return the setting back to the default `false` value  after (for example, in `afterEach()`).